# How to change the layout if I click on the imageButton (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to understand how to make it so that if I click on a imageButton, the layout is changed from item_mode.xml to item_start.xml. I have tried different methods but I always have problems, could someone help me? Thanks :)

This is my code:

```
class TransportAdapter(val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TransportAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var change: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layout = if (change) {
            R.layout.item_start
        } else {
            R.layout.item_mode
        }
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // No need to implement for the start layout
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 1
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val imageButtons: List<ImageButton> = listOf(
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_walk),
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_trotinette),
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_bike),
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_scooter),
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_moto),
        )

        init {
            for (imageButton in imageButtons) {
                imageButton.setOnClickListener {
                    change = true
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use 'if (change)' in getItemViewType(int position) to distinguish between two types of holder

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).